# Identification of the sender in xmpp(jabber) protocol

Tags: c#, xmpp

I don't understand how to determine the sender of a message sent via jabber protocol. If I get message then xml looks like that:

```
<message from="sharok1989@qip.ru/QIP" to="sharok89@gmail.com/Talk.v10576F328E0" stime="1291746351249" xml:lang="ru" type="chat" id="qip_45">
    <body>Hi. I'm fine.</body>
    <active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
</message>
```

There are **from** and **to** attributes.
If I send message then xml looks like that:

```
<message to="sharok1989@qip.ru" type="chat" id="42">
    <body>Hello. How are you?</body>
    <active xmlns="http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates"/>
</message>
```

There is no attribute **from**. How does a client know of who sent him a message?

Sorry for my English. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XMPP server is required to either validate the 'from' attribute if one is specified (to verify that the sender is not attempting to impersonate another client) or to add a 'from' attribute if one was not specified.  In general, you can omit the 'from' and assume that the server will attach one based on the JID of the client connection.

See [RFC 3920](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3920.html#stanzas) (link is to the "XML Stanzas" section) for the precise rules.

Comment: Then I needed to catch the authorization process and save the JID and IP address?I understand it correctly?

Comment: @user348173 - What "identification" are you looking for from a sender? The JID itself is *the* identification in XMPP...

Comment: There are several reasons to keep track of your own JID, the most important of which is so you can tell which presence notifications are from your own connection, so you can ignore them.  Using that JID as the from address is not a good reason.  You should (almost) always just omit the from address as Greg says.  Your server will do the right thing, so that when your contact receives the message, the from address will be set correctly.